# Android app is not connecting to IIS server

Tags: c#, android, json, iis-7

I am trying to connect my android app to iis server using ip address.it works but now it gives me error:
cannot open database login failed for user NT AUTHORITY FOR IUSER

Comment: What does this have to do with Android?

Comment: i have one desktop base application using sql server database and i am connecting my app to that desktop application database using iis server

Comment: That is not related to android, just the way your IIS is visited

Comment: Please provide more details of your entire setup. What kind of application are you running in IIS, how do you connect to the SQL database, etc. Also, in case you are using Windows authentication to connect to your SQL - did you change the user under which your Application pool is running? Or if it's running under your account, did you change your password recently?

Answer (score 1):

Your web app is authenticating to the database using the received credentials in the IIS for the request, depending on how you want to authenticate to the database, you can either:

A) Set the connection string using a specific user/password.

B) Make sure the connection to the IIS is done with valid credential to the
    database, not default IIS anonymous user.

C) Add a login to the database to the anonymous IIS user, this could not be possible is the database and the IIS are on different machines (that user is local to the IIS Server)